# How to add values of multiple rows in SQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

I have a few attribute lists and I want to add all their values.
Example:

```
  ID       Cost1($)      Cost2($)      Cost3($)
2001          23.52          0.53          0.8727
```

We need the total cost (i.e Cost1 + Cost2 + Cost3 as Total Cost).

Comment: Hint:  `select Cost1 + Cost2 + Cost3 as Total Cost from . . . `.  Your question mentions multiple rows, but the sample data has only one row.

Comment: PLEASE TAG PROPERLY.  It's either MySQL or SQL Server, can't be both.  Also what have you tried??????

Comment: If you can't do the query for this, I suggest you don't touch the database.  Get someone else who's more qualified.

Comment: Consider revising your table design

Comment: I think you meant: How to add values of multiple columns?

Answer (score 1):

It's as easy as:

```
SELECT id, (Cost1 + Cost2 + Cost3) AS Total_Cost
FROM your_table
```